# Do sharks never sleep?

Tags: zoology, sleep, sharks

My friend was saying that shark never sleeps. Because to keep it afloat, it has to continuously swim, so that it can't sleep.

This claim is repeated in the [Ocean of Know](http://oceanofk.org/sharks/introShark.html):

> They certainly need to conserve their energy because they never really sleep and most of them never stop swimming.

I know shark has to continuously swim to keep it afloat. But does that mean that sharks never sleep?

Comment: they also need to keep swimming to keep breathing

Comment: @ratchetfreak - no, some do not. COnsider the Wobbegong, which hides on the sea floor and waits, stationary, for its prey.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Spiny Dogfish] <sup>[Spiny Dogfish](http://www.marinebiodiversity.ca/shark/english/spiracle.htm)</sup>

**[Florida Museum of Natural History](http://www.flmnh.ufl.edu/fish/education/questions/basics.html#sleep):**

> It was once believed that all sharks had to swim constantly in order
>   to breathe and could not sleep for more than a few minutes at a time.
>   Oxygen-rich water flows through the gills during movement allowing the
>   shark to breathe.
>
> **While some species of sharks do need to swim
>   constantly, this is not true for all sharks**.
>
> **Some sharks** such as the
>   nurse shark **have [spiracles](http://www.marinebiodiversity.ca/shark/english/spiracle.htm) that force water across their gills
>   allowing for stationary rest**.
>
> **Sharks do not sleep like humans do, but
>   instead have active and restful periods**.

**[ReefQuest Centre for Shark Research](http://www.elasmo-research.org/education/topics/b_sleep.htm)**:

> ... **when it comes to whether or not sharks sleep, we just don't know**.
>
> There have been reports from all over the globe, [including Mexico](http://www.isla-mujeres.com.mx/english/sharks.htm), Japan, and Australia, of sharks resting motionless in caves. These have been called "sleeping sharks", but I can attest that the eyes of these quiescent sharks do follow divers moving about in the caves with them, so they're definitely not asleep.
>
> **From experiments carried out on a small shark called the Spiny Dogfish (*Squalus acanthias*), we know that the 'Central Pattern Generator' that co-ordinates swimming movements in sharks is not located in the brain, but in the spinal chord. Thus, it is possible for an unconscious shark to swim.**
>
> **There is even a possibility that the sharks' fore, mid-, and hind- brain shut down in sequence, resulting in the shark equivalent of sleep-walking**.

**[NEWTON - Ask A Scientist](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/bio99/bio99287.htm)**:

> ... **we don't know whether sharks sleep or not**.
>
> **Many shark species need to constantly swim in order to breathe (or respire) but this does not necessarily mean that they don't "sleep".**
>
> Many animals can **shut down part of their brains for a short time, while keeping other parts "awake" or alert, and watching for predators;**
>
> Other animals **merely slow their brain function for a certain amount of time each day;**
>
> **Sharks may do these things as well**, even though they keep swimming. It's also possible that they don't sleep at all.
>
> The only way for us to find out for sure is to catch them and measure their brain activity all the time.

**[Indianapolis Zoo](http://www.indyzoo.com/SitePages/AboutTheZoo/Sharks.aspx)**:

> **It is unclear how sharks sleep.**
>
> **Some sharks can lie on the bottom
>   while actively pumping water over their gills, but their eyes remain
>   open and actively follow divers**.
>
> When a shark is resting, they do not
>   use their nares, but rather their spiracles. If a shark tried to use
>   their nares while resting on the ocean floor, they would be sucking up
>   sand rather than water. Many scientists believe this is one of the
>   reasons sharks have spiracles.
>
> **The spiny dogfish's spinal cord, rather
>   than its brain, coordinates swimming, so it is possible for a spiny
>   dogfish to continue to swim while sleeping**.
>
> **It is also possible that a
>   shark can sleep with only parts of its brain in a manner similar to
>   dolphins.**

**More:**

- [Sharks.org.za - Sleep](http://www.sharks.org.za/sleep.html)
- [BBC Nature - Surprising Shark Facts](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/uk/indepth/shark-facts.shtml)